# Reactive Programming - call another Mono on completion #SpringWebFlux

Tags: spring-webflux, project-reactor, reactive

I am trying to achieve the following :

I have two methods -
1. public Mono method1 
2. public Mono method2

```
public Mono<Boolean> test(){
 method1.map(status -> {
  if(status.isActive){
    throw Exception;
  } 
 }).switchIfEmpty(method2).thenReturn(true);
}
```

Can you help with :

1. Issue is, control goes to method1, only if method1.subscribe() is used. I am unable to return value or throw exception based on Status field returned from method1.
2. When method1.map() or method1.filter(), control does not even goto method1
3. When method1 returns Mono.empty() then control is not going to switchIfEmpty(method2)

Comment: Looks like your question is broker. Please, make it really clear for us.

Comment: @ArtemBilan - Corrected it, thanks

Comment: Could you improve you question and replace comments with actual code snippets? It's still isn't clear what you're trying to achieve and what the problem is.

Comment: Can you give little more elaborated code snippet? Like method1 implementation or how you're calling test().

Answer (score 1):

Your test method just returns a Publisher. You wont be able to achieve anything with it unless a consumer subscribes to it. This might give you a hint why things might not be working for you as expected.

Also, you haven't even clarified in the question if you're are even calling/subscribing to it or not.